Code disappears in target branch on git merge w/o any indication
I'm having a problem with Git merge. In short, I'm merging the master branch into a feature branch, essentially git checkout feature && git merge master.
This is how it looks graphically:
other branches            O1 --- O2 --- 0x
                            \      \      \
master                       M1 --- M2 --- M3
                               \             \
                                \             \
                                 \             \
                                  \             \
feature                            F1 --- F2 --- staging
                                          ^           ^
                                          |        same code missing here
                                     code present here

What I cannot understand is that:

commit F2 is checked out. The code is present in a file.
I make a merge, there are conflicts (including in the file with the code in question). At this point the code is already missing w/o a trace. I searched with grep over the whole project and in the file where it's supposed to be.
If I resolve the conflicts and commit, the diff of the commit doesn't mention the code removed at all.

Could anyone explain please how this can happen? My intuitive understanding is that if Git removes something it must be reported in the diff at least.
I'm having a feeling that this may have something to do with different merge strategies. But I still can't understand how Git could remove something and not show it in the diff.

If the code was removed in O2, Ox, M2 or M3 then it will be removed upon merge. Do you have revert commits anywhere? How are you merging exactly? Is the code present in M3?

yes, there are reverts in 0x commits and may be in Mx commits, thank you, I'm looking into that direction

No in M3 it's not present. And I'm merging just this way, by default: git merge master and I'm on the feature branch, F2

So the code was removed in the "other" (i.e. master) branch. When you merge that branch, you are also merging the removal of code.

@knittl indeed I'm seeing the file in a revert commit on master and it removes the code.

That's your answer. You merge something that removed the code. The merge result will not have the code (because it was removed in what's being merged)

It still looks very unintuitive, why doesn't Git how the diffs between the current branch's previous commit and the merge commit. This is just a comment

It shows a combined diff for merge commits: only those lines that are different from both parents. If you want to see the diff from one commit to the next, specify it: git diff staging^ staging (first parent) or git diff staging^2 staging (second parent)
